# Sending an object from one point to another

Tags: java

I am working on a simple game in Java and am stuck for now with getting an object to be directed from its current position to a certain point, all at a fixed speed. My problem is that whenever I activate the movement, the object seems to shoot off into a random direction, sometimes towards my target, sometimes away, really any direction it seems, but nothing consistent.

This is what I'm working with:

```
    else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
    {
        double deltaY = 100 - p.getY();
        double deltaX = 100 - p.getX();
        double angle = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * 180 / Math.PI;
        System.out.println(angle);
        double dx = (double) (Math.cos(angle) * 3);
        double dy = (double) (Math.sin(angle) * 3);
        p.setVelX(dx);
        p.setVelY(dy);
    }
```

Here is my SetVel functions as well as the tick method.

```
public void tick()
{
    x+=velX;
    y+=velY;

    if(x <= 0)
        x = 0;
    if(x >= 640)
        x = 640;
    if(y < 0)
        y = 0;
    if(y >= 480)
        y = 480;
}

public void setVelX(double velX)
{
    this.velX = velX;
}

public void setVelY(double velY)
{
    this.velY = velY;
}
```

Using the system outs, and positioning my object at 90 degree angles relative to my target I am getting 90 and 180 degrees, so I don't think its a problem with that.

Comment: A couple of things: are the 100's up there your "destination" (100,100)? You also mention you show us the setVel methods, are you missing the "Vel" in `setX`, `setY` and `this.` in these methods? And what is the 3 intended for?

Comment: The 100, 100 was just a test point with an image there. Sorry about posting the wrong methods, but I fixed it now. And the 3 was just the speed for the object to move towards the other object. Your answer was exactly what I needed though, so thank you VERY much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be coming from the fact that you are using **degrees** to calculate your rotation instead of **radians**.

Here would be a way to fix your issue:

```
else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
{
    double deltaX = p.getDestX() - p.getX();
    double deltaY = p.getDestY() - p.getY();

    double angleRad = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
    double angleDeg = angleRad * 180 / Math.PI;
    System.out.println(angleDeg);
    double dx = (double) (Math.cos(angleRad) * p.getMaxVel());
    double dy = (double) (Math.sin(angleRad) * p.getMaxVel());
    p.setVelX(dx);
    p.setVelY(dy);
}
```

and here would be another way to achieve it:

```
else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
{
    double deltaX = p.getDestX() - p.getX();
    double deltaY = p.getDestY() - p.getY();

    double angleRad = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
    double angleDeg = angleRad * 180 / Math.PI;
    System.out.println(angleDeg);

    double len = Math.sqrt( deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY );
    double unitX = deltaX / len;
    double unitY = deltaY / len;


    double dx = unitX * p.getMaxVel());
    double dy = unitY * p.getMaxVel());
    p.setVelX(dx);
    p.setVelY(dy);
}
```